# PostgreSQL keeps WAL segments not required by any replication slot

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have `wal_keep_segments` set to `3000`. But directory `pg_xlog` contains more than 6000 WAL segments. Interesting thing that there are ~ 3000 files dated after Aug 14, so files dated before Aug 14 should not be exists, I guess. Also these files have an executable bit set.

```
$ ls -al pg_xlog | grep -A2 -B2 00000001000034DB0000003B
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Jul 19 07:58 00000001000034DB00000039
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Jul 19 07:58 00000001000034DB0000003A
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Jul 19 07:58 00000001000034DB0000003B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Aug 14 19:17 0000000100003826000000EA
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Aug 14 19:17 0000000100003826000000EB
```

```

This cluster has no replication slots, `archive_mode` is enabled but `archive_command` is set to `/bin/true`. I think the new WAL segments are recycled and total amount is about 6000 but postgres does not delete the old files for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: A found .ready files for those one which are not deleted in `archive_status` directory.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is not in the habit of setting executable flags on WAL segments.

Besides, it looks like there is a gap in the numbering.

These files must be there by accident, you can delete them.

Comment: I blame barman in this. Understand, that I can remove them but I'm trying to understand what was the reason of this.

Comment: I don't know barman, so I cannot answer that. It is often difficult to reconstruct what happened.